# addAction buttons in notification bar don't appear

Tags: android, notifications

i have this code

```
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setTicker("here is a text")
    .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText ("Alot of text"))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notif)
        .setContentIntent(sender)           
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .addAction(R.drawable.btn_media_play, "Play", PlaypendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.btn_media_pause, "Pause", PausependingIntent)
        .build();      

        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_stat;

        notificationManager.notify(1, n);
```

But in the notification bar (when i send the app in backgorund) it doesnt show the buttons below with Play and Pause, anyone has an ideea why ?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but the java doc for `addAction()` says `Actions will not be displayed when the notification is collapsed` . Try swiping down on the notification to see if actions reveal themselves.

Comment: What is your target SDK Version?

Comment: @Sundeep it doesnt appear the buttons when swiping it down

Comment: The weird thing is that if i run the app on Genymotion, they appear as intended, but when i run it on a tablet, they dont appear at all. (they have both 4.2.2 sdk version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested my app on a galaxy 2 and galaxy 3 and it shows the buttons, but my main problems were:

- in the first place i had to unplug the usb cable from the computer and run the app again in order to see the buttons
- and in second the galaxy tab 3 lite 7.0 (i think it's with tabs) it's as @Sundeep said, but
  you have to wait with you're finger on the notification bar for 1/2
  seconds and then swipe down to appear the buttons added